# Push notifications not working (work only on debug mode)

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

our team is working on an application with push notifications based on ionic with firebase.

Our android build works perfectly and notifications are received.

Notifications also works when running in debug with xcode but when we build the .ipa package and try to install it with impactor notifications are not received, but the token is generated and sent to our backend server. Please help!

Comment: 1) It could be that your you have certain build settings which make your bundleIdentifier in the `.ipa` / release build different from your debug build and as a result your server isn't sending the notification to the correct bundleID. Check if there is any discrepancy between the bundleID you send vs the bundleID of the build. 2) Apple push notification certs has a sandbox cert and a production cert. I don't know how exactly they're different, just know that you can't use one in place of the other... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554638/ios-apns-development-sandbox-vs-production

Comment: I try also to using the automatic management of signature of XCODE, the privisioing profile is generated by xcode. Now when i try to install with Impactor it don't work it say "Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installed/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installed.staging/temp.P48s2z/extracted/Payload/App.app:0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlementes.)

Comment: 1. Can you reply to my previous comments? 2. Update the question with your current state. You may find your answer [The executable gets signed with invalid entitlements in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/the-executable-gets-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-in-xcode)